# How to truncate a column alone in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to truncate a specified column among all the columns in my table?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by 'truncate'

Comment: truncate operation in sql will delete all the records in a table but here I want to delete only the records in a particular column in the table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use a `update` statement without a `where` condition

```
Update tablename 
set column ='' --or NULL
```